# XCode7: "Failed to render instance of" affects all UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uicollectionviewcell

I currently always get an error when using UICollectionViewCells in a Storyboard. No other Controls show this behavior. How can I get rid of them?

[image: Storyboard errors]

This is how one of the affected CollectionViewCells looks like:

[image]

This is how I defined it:

[image: UICollectionViewCell Definition]

Here is the code of the `CategoryCollectionCell`

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

@IBDesignable class CategoryCollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var label: UILabel!

    internal var id : Int?

    override var highlighted : Bool {
        didSet {
            label.textColor = highlighted ? UIColor.greenColor() : UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var text : String? {
        get { return label.text }
        set(value) { label.text = value }
    }

    @IBInspectable var image : UIImage? {
        get { return imageView.image }
        set(value) { imageView.image = value }
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the CollectionViewController:

```
extension CategoryViewController : UICollectionViewController {

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = self.collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(kReuseCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        var categoryCollectionCell = cell as? CategoryCollectionCell
        if categoryCollectionCell == nil {
            categoryCollectionCell = CategoryCollectionCell()
        }

        let data = getDataForIndexPath(indexPath)
        if data != nil {
            categoryCollectionCell?.id = data!.id
            categoryCollectionCell!.text = data!.category
            categoryCollectionCell!.image = data!.image
        }

        return categoryCollectionCell!
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}

extension CategoryViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        guard let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
            return CGSize()
        }

        let width = CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds)
        let padding = flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
        let itemSpacing = flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing
        let size = (width - padding - itemSpacing) / 2
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found that the errors displayed by XCode had nothing to do with the actual problem.

The directory `/Users/{Username}/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` should contain files with names like this: `IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch[...].crash`

Inside them I found stacktraces which led me to the real problem:
The problem lied inside the code of a custom `UITableViewCell` instead of a `UICollectionViewCell`

```
class FooTableCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var checkmarkImageView: UIImageView!

    override internal var selected : Bool {
        didSet {
            checkmarkImageView.hidden = !selected
        }
    }
}
```

The `checkmarkImageView` was `nil` when using the designer. Because of this the Cocoa Storyboard Agent crashed.

I fixed it by adding a guard statement:

```
class FooTableCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var checkmarkImageView: UIImageView!

    override internal var selected : Bool {
        didSet {
            guard let imageView = checkmarkImageView else {
                return
            }

            imageView.hidden = !selected
        }
    }
}
```